# Simple Bootstrap tooltip example not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get bootstrap tool tips working in a simple example. Here's a link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TXPWK/

The tool tip is displaying, however it's just plain text.  Thanks for any help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Broken CSS and the JS needed some fixin' too.

http://jsfiddle.net/ajkochanowicz/TXPWK/6/